# Embedded Tomcat 7 slow compare to Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I recently started embedding Tomcat 7 for my integration tests, rather than Tomcat 6 as I need some of the 7 features and it's our target container. Performance is very slow compared to Tomcat 6 embedded. It's taking in the order of 20 seconds to start the server. This is the code I am using:

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(port);
tomcat.setSilent(true);

tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(webappDir);

tomcat.addWebapp(context, "");    
tomcat.start();
```

Has anyone else experienced this or got suggestions for improving performance? I am running tests on Windows 7, Linux Mint and Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you *just* mean startup time is longer? (That's a pretty narrow measure of performance for servers which are normally expected to be up for days, weeks or months without a restart...)

Comment: I would suggest to use embedded Jetty instead. I have not tried embedded Tomcat, but Jettu run fast enough.

Comment: Jon, it's embedded, so start-up time is what's important here. One would hope that the embedded server was somewhat lighter that the normal one.

Comment: Umar, yes Jetty is nice and quick, but not as featured. I'm likely to need some decent JSP support and support for prettyfaces. Prettyfaces is the main reason for moving from 6 to 7. – Paul Grenyer just now edit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps it's slow due to classpath scanning which is required for annotation-based configuration of Servlet 3.0. If you don't need these features, try to add `metadata-complete="true"` to your `web.xml`.

Comment: Yep, that did it! Got start-up time down to 6 seconds:

Comment: Will this disable annotation-based configuration completely? Or does it just disable the 'scanning' but annotation-based configuration will still work?

Answer (score 5):

This is how it actually looks in web.xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"...
```

Some more info here: [Tomcat and Servlet 3.0 Web Configuration](http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/tomcat-and-servlet-3-0-web-configuration/)