# Apache Tomcat 7 brings slow starting rates with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 6 servlet container to deploy my web applications. Now Tomcat 7 is so mature we're considering a migration to it, but the problem is that we embed it into Eclipse and takes so long to start. I've been researching for a while and found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054791/embedded-tomcat-7-slow-compare-to-tomcat-6), but their solution doesn't work for me.

I've just done an small testing to see its performance with a small application (JSF and EL libraries). Tomcat 6 brings much better results:

```
Tomcat 6 Start -> 1954 ms
Tomcat 7 Start -> 3394 ms
Tomcat 7 Start (metadata-complete=true) -> 3282 ms

Tomcat 6 Debug -> 1981 ms
Tomcat 7 Debug -> 4060 ms
Tomcat 7 Debug (metadata-complete=true) -> 4053 ms
```

Note this tests have been done with **Eclipse kepler** and **latest Tomcat versions** from each branch (6.0.37 and 7.0.50). Also I've considered the result of the second attemp of each test, as the first one could be irrelevant because of deploying requirements, internal configuration changes, etc.

Also that's the header of my deployment configuration file:

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

I changed nothing of the Tomcat default configurations, **it's default for both of them**. Take into account that Tomcat 7 takes 2-3 seconds more to start with this small application. In a medium size deployment, the starting time can increase about 15-20 seconds, which is for us unacceptable.

Here there are the initialization logs:

**Tomcat 6.0.37**

```
ene 20, 2014 12:04:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Cargada la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat 1.1.29 con la versión APR 1.4.8.
ene 20, 2014 12:04:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Capacidades APR: IPv6 [true], enviar fichero [true], aceptar filtros [false], aleatorio [true].
ene 20, 2014 12:04:05 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:basic-jsf' did not find a matching property.
ene 20, 2014 12:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL inicializado correctamente con versión OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
ene 20, 2014 12:04:06 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Inicializando Coyote HTTP/1.1 en puerto http-8080
ene 20, 2014 12:04:06 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Inicializando Coyote AJP/1.3 en ajp-8009
ene 20, 2014 12:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1420 ms
ene 20, 2014 12:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Arrancando servicio Catalina
ene 20, 2014 12:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
ene 20, 2014 12:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\amaeztu\test-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\basic-jsf\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
ene 20, 2014 12:04:06 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.27 ( 20140108-1632 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.1.27@12764) para el contexto '/basic-jsf'
ene 20, 2014 12:04:08 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
ene 20, 2014 12:04:08 PM org.omnifaces.VersionLoggerEventListener processEvent
INFO: Using OmniFaces version 1.6.2
ene 20, 2014 12:04:08 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/basic-jsf/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
ene 20, 2014 12:04:08 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp
INFO: JSF1027: [null] los ELResolvers para JSF no se han registrado con el contenedor JSP.
Initing Bean1
Initing Bean2
Bean1 - Hello!
Initing Bean1
Cleaning Bean1
ene 20, 2014 12:04:08 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Arrancando Coyote HTTP/1.1 en puerto http-8080
ene 20, 2014 12:04:08 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Arrancando Coyote AJP/1.3 en ajp-8009
ene 20, 2014 12:04:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1969 ms
```

**Tomcat 7.0.50**

```
ene 20, 2014 12:04:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Cargada la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat 1.1.29 con la versión APR 1.4.8.
ene 20, 2014 12:04:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Capacidades APR: IPv6 [true], enviar fichero [true], aceptar filtros [false], aleatorio [true].
ene 20, 2014 12:04:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:basic-jsf' did not find a matching property.
ene 20, 2014 12:04:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL inicializado correctamente (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
ene 20, 2014 12:04:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
ene 20, 2014 12:04:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
ene 20, 2014 12:04:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1516 ms
ene 20, 2014 12:04:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Arrancando servicio Catalina
ene 20, 2014 12:04:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
ene 20, 2014 12:04:35 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\amaeztu\test-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\basic-jsf\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
ene 20, 2014 12:04:35 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\amaeztu\test-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\basic-jsf\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
ene 20, 2014 12:04:37 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.27 ( 20140108-1632 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.1.27@12764) para el contexto '/basic-jsf'
ene 20, 2014 12:04:37 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: hay presentes anotaciones PostConstruct/PreDestroy.  Los métodos de beans administrados marcados con estas anotaciones procesarán dichas anotaciones.
ene 20, 2014 12:04:38 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
ene 20, 2014 12:04:38 PM org.omnifaces.VersionLoggerEventListener processEvent
INFO: Using OmniFaces version 1.6.2
ene 20, 2014 12:04:38 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/basic-jsf/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
ene 20, 2014 12:04:38 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp
INFO: JSF1027: [null] los ELResolvers para JSF no se han registrado con el contenedor JSP.
Initing Bean1
Initing Bean2
Bean1 - Hello!
ene 20, 2014 12:04:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
ene 20, 2014 12:04:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
ene 20, 2014 12:04:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3435 ms
```

**Tomcat 7.0.50 (metadata-complete="true")**

```
ene 20, 2014 12:07:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Cargada la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat 1.1.29 con la versión APR 1.4.8.
ene 20, 2014 12:07:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Capacidades APR: IPv6 [true], enviar fichero [true], aceptar filtros [false], aleatorio [true].
ene 20, 2014 12:07:50 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:basic-jsf' did not find a matching property.
ene 20, 2014 12:07:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL inicializado correctamente (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
ene 20, 2014 12:07:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
ene 20, 2014 12:07:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
ene 20, 2014 12:07:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1562 ms
ene 20, 2014 12:07:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Arrancando servicio Catalina
ene 20, 2014 12:07:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
ene 20, 2014 12:07:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\amaeztu\test-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\basic-jsf\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
ene 20, 2014 12:07:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\amaeztu\test-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\basic-jsf\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
ene 20, 2014 12:07:54 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.27 ( 20140108-1632 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.1.27@12764) para el contexto '/basic-jsf'
ene 20, 2014 12:07:54 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: hay presentes anotaciones PostConstruct/PreDestroy.  Los métodos de beans administrados marcados con estas anotaciones procesarán dichas anotaciones.
ene 20, 2014 12:07:55 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
ene 20, 2014 12:07:55 PM org.omnifaces.VersionLoggerEventListener processEvent
INFO: Using OmniFaces version 1.6.2
ene 20, 2014 12:07:55 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/basic-jsf/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
ene 20, 2014 12:07:55 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp
INFO: JSF1027: [null] los ELResolvers para JSF no se han registrado con el contenedor JSP.
Initing Bean1
Initing Bean2
Bean1 - Hello!
Initing Bean1
Cleaning Bean1
ene 20, 2014 12:07:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
ene 20, 2014 12:07:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
ene 20, 2014 12:07:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3316 ms
```

The only difference I can notice in logs is that Tomcat 6 scans only a jar file while 7 scans two. Adding *metadata-complete="true"* doesn's seem to make any difference. Does anybody had similar issues?

Comment: [Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Annotation_scanning) are two other tweeks descried, have you tried them?

Comment: Going with 3.0 deployment instead of 2.5 and with `metadata-complete="true"` and `<absolute-ordering />` makes it around 1 sec faster. Still 0,5 sec slower than Tomcat 6 (which is ~25% slower starting up). Anyway, thanks for the link ;-)

Comment: It's definitly a Tomcat7 + Servlet spec 3.0 thing. Just to let you know it can go worst: `INFO: Server startup in 23279 ms` ... a pretty large application, with tomcat6 I had at most 3 secs startup time :/

Comment: Yeah, but I consider a pitfall having to wait 25% more. Supposing an app takes about 45 secs to start, it's actually 11 secs more per starting up. If when debugging we start-stop the server around 100 times per day, just calculate how much time we're wasting...

Comment: Tomcat7 must search for annotations inside classes, so it makes sense it takes more time to start than  Tomact6. Is just a context reload not enough? Do you really require a full service restart? Context reload is much faster than service restart.

Comment: @cedric which is the difference between a context reload and service restart from eclipse view point?

Comment: Context reload only reload the current context (project). It's MUCH faster.

Comment: @cedric I'm working with eclipse and m2e wtp plugin. This plugin just deploys everything to the server when saving, but has the problem that can't do hot deploys of java code/configurations , so I usually have to restart the embedded tomcat instance. I actually work with only one project - context when I'm developing.